# jQuery html transition

Tags: jquery, synchronization, transition

I'm still learning jQuery and what I'm trying to do right now is combining the `html()` method with a transition ( e.g. `hide()` and `show()` ) in order to change the html of a div with a transition effect. This is what I tried:

```
$('div.content_box').hide(1000).html(return_html).show(1000);
```

Where `div.content_box` is the div which's content/HTML should be changed with a transition and return_html contains the html that was returned by a PHP file which was requested through the `ajax()` method.

However, this does not give me the desired result. Instead of first hiding the div, then changing its html and then showing it again, it already changed the div's HTML content when it's still hiding it.

Does anyone know how I can make this work properly (where the actions are executed in proper order and one at a time)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are many ways to archive what you want:

Using callback on [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/): http://jsfiddle.net/VbkNE/

```
$('div.content_box').hide(1000, function() {
    $(this).html(return_html).show(1000);
});
```

Using [queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/): http://jsfiddle.net/VbkNE/1/

```
$('div.content_box').hide(1000).queue(function(next) {
    $(this).html(return_html);
    next();
}).show(1000);
```

Using native [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout): http://jsfiddle.net/VbkNE/2/

```
$('div.content_box').hide(1000);
setTimeout(function() {
    $('div.content_box').html(return_html).show(1000)
}, 1000);
```

Using [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) doesn't work in your case, quote from jQuery API - delay:

> Only subsequent events in a queue are delayed; for example this will not delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide() which do not use the effects queue.

I would go for the callback method in this case - cause you don't need to redefine your selector as in setTimeout and you don't need to shift the queue stock as in `next()` in the queue example, but note how powerful the queue method is. Ex for chaining AJAX calls.

Comment: Thank you for putting up the possible ways to fix my problem! Got it working now :).

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery delay() in your chain: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

I think using hide() and show() in one chain will not work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I tried delay() as well but it did not prevent them methods from being executed at the same time. The html() method was still executed at the same time as the hide() method, even when putting a delay() method inbetween of them.

Comment: Only methods that make use of the effect queue can be delay()ed.